# Silent mode for solver CPLEX using AMPL

Tags: cplex, ampl

Is there any silent mode to run a AMPL script using CPLEX as a solver.

I am sure the option

```
option solver_msg 0;
```

will make it silent but it still output CPLEX version number to the console.

How can I make it totally silence.
Because I think the console output will dramatically cost running time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suppress all output by redirecting it to `/dev/null` (or `NUL` on Windows) in addition to setting `solver_msg` to 0:

```
option solver_msg 0;
solve > /dev/null;
```

That said, most of the solver running time is usually spent in optimization algorithms, not output.